# Discord Music Bot error discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'videoId'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord music bot and using YouTube's Data API, I am trying to fetch the song just by typing in its name instead of URL and I have been facing some interesting problems.

The fetch songs using words feature worked initially with a major flaw, it could only take in messages with 1 word in it. Here is the code for the entire sequence which worked.

```py
@client.command(pass_context = True, aliases = ['p'])
async def play(ctx, song_name: str):
    song_pack = rq.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q={}&key={}".format(final_song_name, YOUTUBE_API)).json()
    song_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(song_pack['items'][0]['id']['videoId'])

    def check_queue():
        Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
        if Queue_infile is True:
            DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue"))
            length = len(os.listdir(DIR))
            still_q = length - 1

            try:
                first_file = os.listdir(DIR)[0]
            except:
                print("No more queued song(s)\n")
                queues.clear()
                return

            main_location = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            song_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath("Queue") + "\\" + first_file)

            if length != 0:
                print("Song done, playing next queued\n")
                print(f"Songs still in queue: {still_q}")
                song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")

                if song_there:
                    os.remove("song.mp3")
                shutil.move(song_path, main_location)

                for file in os.listdir("./"):
                    if file.endswith("mp3"):
                        os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')

                voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after = lambda e: check_queue())
                voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
                voice.source.volume = 0.7

            else:
                queues.clear()
                return

        else:
            queues.clear()
            print("No songs were queued before the ending of the last song\n")

    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
            queues.clear()
            print('Removed old song file')
    except PermissionError:
        print("Trying to delete song file, but, it is being played.")
        await ctx.send("ERROR: Music Playing")
        return


    Queue_infile = os.path.isdir("./Queue")
    try:
        Queue_folder = "./Queue"
        if Queue_infile is True:
            print("Removed old Queue folder")
            shutil.rmtree(Queue_folder)
    except:
        print("No old queue folder")

    await ctx.send("**Searching for** `{}` :mag_right:".format(song_name))

    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild = ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'quiet': True,
    'postprocessors':[{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        print("Downloading audio now\n")
        ydl.download([song_url])

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            print(f"Renamed File: {file}\n")
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after = lambda e: check_queue())
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.7

    nname = name[:-16]
    await ctx.send(f"**Playing** :musical_note: : `{nname}`")
    print("Playing\n")
```

But when I try to fix the flaw by just adding this in the 4th line with proper indentation

```py
    final_song_name = song_name.replace(" ", "_")
```

I get the error.

Here is an example JSON from the YouTube API.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "OvvXoVaLuxf9xsl2hEiI-iG1Hs4",
  "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
  "regionCode": "IN",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 3994,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "6ooIFJrvuNFu7tLWPM_CbRXyp4s",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "TfdHSJxVPCk"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2013-02-05T00:17:42Z",
        "channelId": "UCJLX0B8m1KrS6oe3xageAbQ",
        "title": "Archie - Famous (Original Mix) [Monstercat Release]",
        "description": "Archie - Famous (Original Mix) [Monstercat Release] Hope you enjoy & don't forget to subscribe! :D.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TfdHSJxVPCk/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TfdHSJxVPCk/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TfdHSJxVPCk/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Domsn House",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2013-02-05T00:17:42Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I think what I did is correct. I even made a new program with the following code

```py
song_name = str(input('Enter Song Name:'))
final_song_name = song_name.replace(" ", "_")
song_pack = rq.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q={}&key={}".format(final_song_name, YOUTUBE_API)).json()
song_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(song_pack['items'][0]['id']['videoId'])
print(song_url)
```

And it worked fine, fetching me the url after having many words as input.
This is one of my first questions here. Excuse me for my incompetence or (expected) stupidity.

Also, **rq =  requests module**

Comment: `youtube-dl` supports searching. add `'default_search': 'auto'` to your `ydl_opts` dictionary. `youtube-dl` will then search if given a string (URL still works the same as before).